# RawPrinterHelper unable to print Barcode using ESC POS Commands

Tags: c#, printing, escpos

A relatively simple task is turning into hours of frustration so here goes:

I have various Thermal printers and we print to the using the RawPrinterHelper that Microsoft posted.
Usually use a String builder build the string and call the SendStringToPrinter and we have a printed piece of paper.

I'm trying to print a simple barcode via the ESC/POS commands that are supported. WE use these for other functions (cutting, change font sizes) that all works, the barcode refuses to print.

ESC POS Command is : GS k m n d1 d2 … dn
m：barcode type e.g. 
n：barcode length -indicates the number of bar code data bytes
d1 the barcode

The question I have is, How do I send the length of the barcode? 
I believe this where my problem lies.

The code snippet:

```
StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
barcode = "1234567890";
char commandGS = '\x1D';
char linefeed = '\x0A';
char esc = '\x1B';
char commandFontSize = '\x21';
char commandk = '\x6B';
char code128 = '\x69';
print.Append(commandGS);
print.Append(commandk);
print.Append(code128);
print.Append(barcode.Length);
print.Append(barcode);
string printJob = print.ToString();
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, printJob);
```

Comment: Check your encoding. it must be ascii

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a byte to represent the length of the barcode rather than the text representation of the length of the barcode.

So instead of

```
print.Append(barcode.Length);
```

use

```
print.Append((char)barcode.Length);
```

I assume the length does not exceed 255.

**Edited to add:** You can examine the bytes which you are sending with something like

```
var bb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(printJob);
bb.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x.ToString("X2") + " "));
```

and check that they conform to what you intend to send. You may also want to compare what is sent to something which *does* work in your current code.

Comment: @user3725237 I added a suggestion to check the bytes which are being sent.