# Printing barcodes on a bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode, thermal-printer

I am working with a bluetooth thermal printer and was able to print normal text and invoice's as well. But i am not able to print barcodes.

I am generating barcode with ZXING library

```
OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();

String text = mEditText.getText().toString();

MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text,BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,200,200);

BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();

Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);

os.write("Hello".getBytes()); //Prints Hello
```

How can i print the bitmap using the same logic ?

I have tried some codes like

```
int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);

byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

os.write(byteArray);
```

But this gives a blank print and roll keep rolling

I am using Godex-MX30 printer

Comment: Ask the printer manufacturer.

Comment: Do not have Developer support for Android application from the Vendor, also this printer is able to printer barcode using 3rd Part Applications from play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.com.UtilIntelligenceCPCL_Demo&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the printer that you are sending an image to print and specify how to print it.

Typically this is done with ESC/POS codes.  Most printers like this use ESC/POS codes.

ESC * is how that is specified.  You can look at the many examples in this questions [java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269019/print-bitmap-full-page-width-in-thermal-dot-printer-using-esc-pos-in-java) or in this [one's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545781/esc-pos-image-in-java) as well.

For more information, see Seiko Epson [reference](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=88).

Not sure about this printer, but many of thermal receipt printers have support for creating and printing barcodes also using Esc/Pos Code.  You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132105/rawprinterhelper-unable-to-print-barcode-using-esc-pos-commands).